# Stanford-NLP Parser incorrectly splits my sentence

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I'm using the Stanford Parser to parse my corpus (for Machine Translation) to constituency trees. I am able to get the parser to work just fine, both through the GUI and the command line, but one problem I'm having is how it basically 'defines a line'.

Usually, when working with a corpus, a sentence is an entire string of words until it reaches a new line. With the Stanford parser, it seems to take a sentence to be up until an 'end-of-sentence character' like a full stop or question mark. In some situations,this ends with incorrectly taking a portion of a sentence to be an entire sentence on its own, which inflates the number of sentences I have and causes misalignment with my target dataset.
Is there any way I can get the parser to take a sentence to be up until the `\n` newline, or is it just defined this way?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `ssplit.eolonly` it will treat the text as one sentence per line.

Comment: That is assuming using the full CoreNLP pipeline. If you need to use the standalone parsing distribution, I can look in to how to set that setting in that case.